# How to go to the beginning of a command

Tags: command-line

If I am editing a command, for example:

```
:set paste
```

And my cursor is between the `p` and `a`:

```
:set pa|ste
```

I can go to the end of the command text by doing `ctrl-e`. However it doesn't seem like `ctrl-a` works to go to the start of the text. Is there a shortcut that I can use to go to the start of a command I'm typing? For example, I'd like to be able to enter a key(s) to be able to get to:

```
:|set paste
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set command line mappings with `cmap`.

In your case:

```
cnoremap <c-a> <Home>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, Vim command line uses `Ctrl-B` to go to the beginning of the line. Execute `:h cmdline-editing` to see more key bindings.

Most command line tools follow the Emacs key bindings, and you can write your own mappings if you want. See `:help cnoremap` for details. There are also plugins, like [rsi](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi) that do it for you

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl-F` is very handy as it puts the current command line in an editable window, that also shows history. You can use all the Vim commands here to edit the current command, including traversing earlier commands in history.